# How to join a channel in Hyperledger from another server?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, peers, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I've deployed a chaincode on my VM i.e 192.168.4.110. Everything is working fine when I test it locally.

Now I want my second VM i.e 192.168.4.112 to connect with the above Hyperledger's vm Channel.

But I can't find out the way or anything to connect them.
Basically I don't know how to create a proper network for the Hyperledger.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciable.